# Which is the alternative to "workspace()" in julia 1.0?

Tags: julia

0.7 warns to use [revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl), but on its documentation I just can't find a command to just say "clean it all".

Yes, I can sure just restart Julia, but in an IDE is several clicks away, while sometimes I just want to clean all variables/modules previously defined..

Comment: I guess its currently not doable: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/removal-of-workspace-and-a-way-to-clear-variables/11107/11

Comment: At the moment, it seems like the only way to simulate such a flexible 'workspace' seems to be to hold a 'dictionary' of variables instead of assigning them straight into the Main module, i.e. something like `Workspace = Dict([:a => 1, :b => 2])` etc. Which also means you need to know your workspace is going to need to be flexible in advance of you using the REPL session. And which is also totally cumbersome. But this seems to be a limitation of the language and its internals (strength as a weakness and all that).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou you know that's terrible. Seriously, a module-based workflow is the way to handle names in Julia, even though method deletion isn't (yet) a thing

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard of course it's terrible! That's why I say it's a limitation of the language, even if in theory a justified one; Julia sacrifices some flexibility w.r.t. interactive REPL sessions, in exchange for strengths intended for standalone programs, where the expectation is that everything is properly scoped and that unnecessary littering of the workspace does not take place.

Comment: Well you made the terrible suggestion after I'd answered the question correctly...

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard ouch xD. Ok I get the point (and humour) but we're splitting hairs. The point is, effectively what all such `how can I clear a variable` requests have been alluding to ever since julia 0.1, is functionality similar to matlab's dynamic workspace, where you can clear isolated variables at will, while trying things out in the console. In julia, for better or worse, there is no such thing, and this is by design. The module hack below is neat, but that aside, alas, currently the only way to emulate a truly dynamic workspace for an interactive julia session is with a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, I can sure just restart Julia, but in an IDE is several clicks away

Assuming you are using Juno,
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.
[Docs](http://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/basic_usage.html)

This <kbd>k</kbd>ills  the julia process, which will then automatically restart.
It is fairly fast

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to work with your code inside a module MyModule, then use Atom/Juno's inbuilt ability to define the working module in the left-most part of the bottom bar. Reevaluating the module should clear everything.

Comment: I haven't used Juno, but does this allow you to do what OP is asking? Namely evaluate something interactively into temporary variables and then delete them from the workspace and continue working?

Comment: Yes of course. That's why I suggested it :trollface: Try this: Open a source file in Atom, and give it the contents `module Test;; end`, save it somewhere as "test.jl" and run the contents (shift-cmd-enter). Then open the console and click in the lower right corner where it says "Main" and change the working module for the console (or any source file) to "Main.test". In the console define some variables and a function: `y = 2; f(x) = "foo"; f(y)`. Then reevaluate the source file. Voila! Your console workspace is empty again (or rather only holds what is in the module). Without breaking Main.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your `startup.jl` file, and `workspace()` should  work essentially the same as on previous Julia releases:

```
function workspace()
   atexit() do
       run(`$(Base.julia_cmd())`)
   end
   exit()
end
```